# nginx regex: detect if delimiter is present

Tags: regex, bash, nginx

I have a string that looks like any of the following:

```
1) /tag/example/123
2) /tag/example/123/
3) /tag/example/123/1v1
4) /tag/example/123/1v1/yes/no/maybe
```

I am doing a rewrite in nginx on this string that looks like this:

```
rewrite ^/tag/example/(\d*)/(.*) /example/$1/$2;
```

The $uri needs to end up looking like /example/123 for string 1). /example/123/1v1 for string 3). And so on...

With this rewrite, I need $1 to be 123 and $2 to be the rest of the string. If there is nothing after 123 (string 1), I need $2 to simply be null. This regex works for 2), 3) and 4), but does not work for 1). 1) makes the rewrite abort because the / is not present after the 123.

Outputs:

```
1) Aborts
2) $1 = 123, $2 = NULL
3) $1 = 123, $2 = 1v1
4) $1 = 123, $2 = 1v1/yes/no/maybe
```

How can I get this to work for all the strings?

Comment: I think you just want to remove `/tag` from the beginning of each URL, without worrying about what follows it. I'm not familiar with `nginx`, but it looks like `rewrite ^/tag/(.*) /$1` would work.

Comment: Unfortunately I need to be able to separate the number (123) from the rest of it. So $1 will have the number only, and the rest will be stored in $2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try it like this?

```
rewrite ^/tag/example/(\d*)/?(.*) /example/$1/$2;
```

Comment: Thats it! I just realized I became a victim of cache. I was testing through a proxy server going through a web browser and since I didnt clear my cache and I left the strings the same, it was parsing old requests.

I tried this before, but must have routed to some old cached address. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this translates to nginx, but for Perl regular expressions you'll need to use the non-capturing parentheses like so:

```
s^(?:/tag)?(?:/example)((((/\d*)(/)?)(1v1)?)(/yes/no/maybe)?)^example/$1$2$3$4^g
```

I'm afraid I've used '^' in place of / to keep the answer straightforward - I couldn't say whether it's possible to use that substitution in nginx, but I think the regex holds good.

Comment: I didnt make it too clear, but the only know literal from the string is /tag/example/ and the 123 section must be a number (which is why i used \d*), but it could be any number. The 1v1 and other sections can all be different strings or numbers or combination of both.

Answer (score 0):

I think you solved your problem, but in the unlikely event that someone else can't see how to modify the code to allow for any combinations of alphanumeric characters between the slashes, I think this should be good:

```
s^(?:/tag)?(?:/example)((((/\d*)(/)?)(\w+?)?)(/w+?/w+?/w+?)?)^example/$1$2$3$4^g
```